# Plot labels in matlab graphic

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I want to make a graphic in Matlab.
Let's say I have a set `[1,3,5]` for x and `[0.2,0.4,0.5]` for y. Is it possible to plot a graphic that has a label on it instead of just a point or line. For example, in coordinate x=1 and y=0.2 it is written "event1" and in coordinate x=3 and y=0.4 it is written "event2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do something like this:

```
x = [1 3 5];
y = [0.2 0.4 0.5]
my_str = {'event 1';'event 2';'event 3'};
figure
text(x,y,my_str);
axis([0.8*min(x) 1.2*max(x) 0.8*min(y) 1.2*max(y)])
```